# filtering a list with elisp remove-if

Tags: emacs, filter, functional-programming, elisp

To filter a list with emacs lisp, one should use the `remove-if` function. The following is the documentation for `remove-if:`

```
remove-if is an alias for `cl-remove-if' in `cl.el'.

(remove-if PREDICATE SEQ [KEYWORD VALUE]...)

Remove all items satisfying PREDICATE in SEQ.
This is a non-destructive function; it makes a copy of SEQ if necessary
to avoid corrupting the original SEQ.

Keywords supported:  :key :count :start :end :from-end
```

Here is an example of `remove-if` not acting like I think it should:

```
(defvar states '( ('USA 'PA) ('USA 'VA) ('USA 'CA) ))
(remove-if (lambda (row) (not (equal (cadr row) 'CA))) states)
```

I want this should return `('CA)` but it does not. Instead it returns `nil.`

1. Why is the above example returning `nil` instead of `('CA)`?

Thanks for all the help!

**EDIT:**

I see that if I change my definition of `states` to not quote the entries then what I have written works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put quotes inside the list. Just quoting the list is enough:

```
(defvar states '( (USA PA) (USA VA) (USA CA) ))
```

The return value in this case is:

```
((USA CA))
```